# Prevent button click from activating <tr> onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I have a table with a row that contains a button within one of the cells. The `<tr>` has an onclick event. I want the button to operate independently of the `<tr>` onclick yet operate within the same row.

**HTML:**

```
<tr onclick="$trigger();">
   <td>Data A</td>
   <td>Data B</td>
   <td>Data C</td>
   <td><button onclick="$buttonClicked();">Submit</button></td>
</tr>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use **[event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)**:

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any
>   parent handlers from being notified of the event.

```
$('button').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Lifesaving answer!

Answer (score 5):

This is event bubbling, which is causing the parent click to be activated.

```
$('button').click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

If your browser is IE<9, try this:

```
$('button').click(function(e) {
   e.cancelBubble();
});
```

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Comment: Yeah it was event ordering. Thankyou for your help.